# WSO2 ESB Tutorial Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I just want know if somebody here already tried this tutorial:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sending+a+Simple+Message+Through+the+ESB

I followed the instructions strictly but after I deployed my SampleCApp Composite Application project to carbon 4.4 based server(wso2esb-5.0.0), the SimpleStockQuoteProxy is nowhere to be located in the management console.

I hope you can help me with this especially those who have encountered this issue. I want to know, how did you fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of OS are you using? If you are using Windows, unfortunately, it doesn't work. At least I haven't found a way to make it work through the Developer Studio.

But you can login into the management console, then in the Main tab, Carbon Applications, Add and upload your exported .car file. Refresh the List of Carbon Applications a few times until you see it there or until it shows the red message that the uploaded Carbon Application is faulty. You can click on the message and remove the faulty application, if this happens.

You can export the file by right-clicking on the Composite Application Project in the Developer studio and selecting Export Composite Application Project.